# Finding the least nonnegative residue from large exponents

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find the least nonnegative residue if n=$16^{16}$ and m=6

So far i have that $16\equiv -2\pmod 6$, so $16^{16}\equiv (-2)^{16}\pmod 6$

Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $ 2^2=-2 (mod 6)$

Hence, 2^(16)=$2^8=2^4=2^2 (mod  6)$due to the repeated application of the relation given in the first line.

Hence answer is 4

Comment: Why can't you go one step further from $2^2$ to $2^1$?

Comment: No! Because $2^2=-2 (mod 6)$ but you asked for non negative residues so we have to stop there.

Comment: Also note that actually $2^8 = (-2)^4 (mod 6) $ but since 4 is an even power I have directly written $2^4$.